# psycopg2 - insert into table from array

Tags: python, psycopg2

Throughout my script I create a fairly long list that then I need to insert into my database. I want to know if there's a way to direct create a SQL statement with the contents of the array instead of overdoing something like:

```
cursor.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO 
                my_table 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, /* 'til almost infinity */);''', 
            (list[0], list[1], list[3]... /* again almost until infinity */))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string formatting` and `join` to achieve the VALUES expansion, using the length of your data `list`. You can then just use a `list` or `tuple` as is for the actual values.  Something like:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO my_table VALUES({})""".format(','.join('%s' for x in my_list)), data)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''INSERT INTO 
        my_table 
    VALUES (''' + ','.join(['%s' for x in mylist]) + ''');''', 
    mylist
)
```

Use `','.join(['%s' for x in mylist])` to create a comma separated string of placeholders for your data.

Comment: I did not know you could use * in such manner. It doesn't seem to work in this context, though.

Comment: @JDGamboa how about without the `*`? Unfortunately, I don't have access to a PG database to test.